# Applications/Software required after installing 12.10

Tags: software-recommendation, 12.10

For the first time, I have installed Ubuntu in my laptop. I have installed the latest version i.e 12.10, but I am facing the following issues after installation:

1. I could not connect my reliance data card to it.
2. If i play a song it is asking me python software to install.
3. Also could not find the players in it.

Hence, can any one please let me know the necessary software for a new Linux user.

Can any one please help me out in learning new things in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

in a terminal windows type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` to get all of the MP3 decoders, Flash, Java and the generally necessary apps. You data card might require a restricted driver. Try going to SOFTWARE SOURCES while your card is connected to see it recommends anything.

Answer (score 1):

Rhythmbox is the default music player for Ubuntu. It should either be in the side bar, or if you click on the Ubuntu logo (top left of your screen) and type the 'rhy' in the search box, that should also bring up the Rhythmbox app. Hope that helps your no.3 question, and welcome aboard!